# Floating action button not responding to click

Tags: android, android-layout, android-coordinatorlayout

I have a floating action button in an activity which i plan to display over fragments. The FAB doesnot repond to clicks while the ripple is visible.
I searched SO for similar questions but the answers I found didnot work.

Here is my layout for the FAB.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:theme="@style/MyTheme">

<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/MainActivityFragmentContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</FrameLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/homeFAB"
    android:layout_width="65dp"
    android:layout_height="65dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_add_image"
    android:onClick="runThis"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/MainActivityFragmentContainer"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|center" />
```

I rearranged the order of the button in the layout inside the coordinator layout but did not work.
Then I added `android:onclick="runThis"` to the FAB in the XML and a method in the activity.

```
    public void runThis(View view) {
    Toast.makeText(SlidingMenuActivity.this, "CLICKED", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Getting below error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected receiver of type
>   xxx.xxx.SlidingMenuActivity, but got
>   android.support.v7.internal.view.ContextThemeWrapper

Please help me figure out what I am missing.
Thank you

Comment: try replacing SlidingMenuActivity.this with view.getContext()

Comment: @poss okay I'll try that and let you know what happens

Comment: Related Google Code discussion [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=174871)

Comment: Don't use floatingactionbutton view and DrawerLayout view in the same layout; if you are using in same layout

Comment: I had forgotten to initialise the view in the activity which was giving me problems.

Answer (score 1):

Try with below code and pass instead of `SlidingMenuActivity`
    with `getApplicationContext()`. It should work.

```
FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using fragments you should use click listener instead of defining onClick on xml like this....
inflate fab on onCreate view...

```
FloatingActionButton myFab = (FloatingActionButton) myView.findViewById(R.id.homeFAB); 
myFab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
    public void onClick(View v) { 
        doyourThing(); 
    } 
});
```

or 
replace SlidingActivity.this with getActivity()

Comment: I think he really uses Activity, but that should apparently work.